# MessageBox.Show over maximized windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following code to handle error when application is started.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new NAudioTutorial5());
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
        MessageBox.Show("Please contact the developers with "
           + "the following information:\n\n" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace,
           "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("error.log", ex.Message.ToString() + " " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

in Program.cs file. While in main file I have the following code to maximize windows form.

```
private void hello_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = true;
    //this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Thus when their is application exception the messageBox is popped up behind main windows form. How can I change my code to show messageBox in front of windows form. I tried

```
MessageBox.Show(this, "hello");
```

But this keyword cann't be used in static method. Is their nay way to handle this problem. I want to show messageBox in front of maximized windows form.

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but instead of using ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, you may find it better to simply use ex.ToString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the currently active form for the application.